# Huawei Ads Kit (Monetization apps) from account registered in my country as individual not allowed?

Tags: huawei-developers, appgallery, appgallery-connect

I'm trying to integrante Huawei Ads Kit to my apps published to Huawei AppGallery.

Is it correct that I have to do it on the following page from the screenshot?

[image]

But the problem that I see the following page when I select it:

[image]

Does it mean that I'm not yet allowed to use Huawei Monetazation yet in my country as individual or did I just select the wrong service (where should I setup banners and so on)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it seems depends on where you are:

In some countries it is only possible for enterprise accounts that have completed identity verification process to use the Petal Ads Publisher Service.

The list of countries/regions that Petal Ads Publisher Service is available in:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/monetize/restriction-0000001061730052